# How to execute SQL query from two database

Tags: sql-server

I want to know how to execute sql query from two database, one database is a remote server and next one is my local database, so from both the database table I want to use JOIN query.

Is it possible to do in SQL server management studio 2016 ?

If it is possible please guide how to do so.

Thanks,
Manu.

Comment: Look for [sp_addlinkedserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [OPENDATASOURCE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Hi Manu,  take a look at this post on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406989/sql-query-across-multiple-sql-servers

Answer (score 0):

As @Akina mentioned linked server might be a way to go. if you create linked server with name RemoteServer your query may look like:

```
  Select * from myLocalDatabase.dbo.myLocalTable  mlt 
    join RemoteServer.RemoteDatabase.dbo.myRemoteTable mrt
    on mlt.col1 = mrt.col1
```

Be aware of performance penalty when running remote joins.
in certain cases you might be better importing data to local server and then joining it especially if this is going to repeat more often.

As for creation of linked server you could try this to add another SQL Server

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'RemoteServerDescription', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI11', @datasrc=N'RemoteServername_or_IP', @catalog=N'databasename'

USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'RemoteServerDescription', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'True'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz and Akina for the response, I have gone through that link of sp_addlinkedserver, but I've no idea how to get the details for these as given below -

Comment: sp_addlinkedserver [ @server= ] 'server' [ , [ @srvproduct= ] 'product_name' ]   
     [ , [ @provider= ] 'provider_name' ]  
     [ , [ @datasrc= ] 'data_source' ]   
     [ , [ @location= ] 'location' ]   
     [ , [ @provstr= ] 'provider_string' ]   
     [ , [ @catalog= ] 'catalog' ]

Comment: Please go through below link for how to add linked server in SQL --> https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/